# String replace then split breaks after multiple entries angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, split

i'm trying to break multiple strings on the \n entry inside a string. currently the code is as followed:

```
<p ng-if="controller.service.variable" class="card-text" ng-repeat="factor in controller.service.variable.replace('\n\n','\n').split('\n')">{{factor}}</p>
```

This works just fine when there are two \n\n inside the string, when theres more then two, the split breaks and no longer shows anything.

the \n\n replace was supposed to fix this in a earlier bug, where two \n\n would break the string aswell. 
any ideas?

Current test data being split:

```
gjdfbjgd\n\njffsjfsbf\n\nsfj \n\nfsbfsssfsfsf
```

Comment: you can use split with regex `.split(/\n*/)`, also no need of `replace`

Comment: @AZ_Data is now showing up, but not breaking lines propperly like it should with \n

Comment: my bad it should be `.split(/\n+/)`

Comment: @AZ_Still seems to showing up with spaces instead of the intended \n enters

Comment: can you paste your data you are splitting?

Comment: @AZ_Edited the post with the test data trying to split on

Comment: if you want to remove the spaces as well, use `.split(/\n+\s*/)`

Comment: @AZ_Sorry i don't think I was very clear. The lines are supposed to break on the \n\n parts. Data is received from a database with hard string that have \n\n in there. printing this won't actually show the enters, this is what the split is for.

Answer (score 1):

turned out to be a simple fix.
Added the CSS: White-space:pre-wrap which fixed it.

Comment: Everyone was busy trying to fix it programmatically all the while there was a simple css fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.split` with the regex.

```js
let str  =`gjdfbjgd

jffsjfsbf

sfj 




fsbfsssfsfsf`;
console.log(str.split(/\n+/))
```

If string includes `\n`

```js
let str  =`gjdfbjgd\\n\\njffsjfsbf\\n\\nsfj\\n\\n\\n\\nfsbfsssfsfsf`;
console.log(str)
console.log(str.split(/[\\n]+/))
```

Comment: Giving this a try and right now it's return the following error with this expression: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 50-50 [\] in expression [datagathering.wam.IDD_Technical_Factor__c.split(/[\n]+/].

Comment: When i remove one \n it will return the following error Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary expression at column 49 of the expression [datagathering.wam.IDD_Technical_Factor__c.split(/[
]+/)] starting at [/[
]+/].

Comment: why you tried `.split(/[\n]+/]` not `.split(/[\\n]+/]`?